# Pythonic way of closing range after last iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I have a code style problem and I'm looking for a pythonic implementation of what I wrote below.

The (simplified) code I posted iterates through a sequence and returns ranges. Each range starts and ends with a specific condition. Ranges cannot be overlapping. I'm using a variable `active` to track if the start of a range has already been found. If at the end of the sequence the active range hasn't been closed, it should be added (with `input_length` as end index)

The code below works as expected, but I don't like the fact that I had to write the code to append the range to the results list twice. In the real problem I have, this block is way longer and I don't want to write it a second time after the for-loop.

Do you have any suggestions how I can improve this?

Thanks!

```
input_length = 100
results = []

active = False
start = None
for i in range(input_length):
    condition = i % 9 == 0
    if not active and condition:
        active = True
        start = i

    condition2 = i % 13 == 0
    if active and condition2:
        active = False
        # do some additional calculations...
        results.append((start, i))

if active:
    # do some additional calculations...
    results.append((start, input_length))

print(active)
print(results)
```

Comment: Working code that needs to be reviewed/improvied is better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to it is to edit the inner condition:

```
    condition2 = i % 13 == 0
    if active and (condition2 or i == input_length-1))
        active = False
        # do some additional calculations...
        results.append((start, i if condition2 else i + 1))
```

and remove the outer.

If you want to avoid the `i if condition2 else i + 1` maybe you can iterate on `range(input_length + 1)`? (it depends on what other things you do in the loop)

Comment: You have an off-by-one error. You need to compare `i == input_length-1`, but then you can't just do `results.append((start, i))`.

Comment: @Rawing You right, I fixed that, although I'm not sure if thats a good solution for him now.

Comment: hmm the problem with this solution is that a sequence where the last element fulfills the condition and one where it doesn't lead to the same range.

Comment: @caenyon thats right :( you consider the suggestion at the end of my post?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that before... The problem is that this introduces problems when using i as index of a list of length input_length in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice way how to do that:

```
import itertools as it

il = 100
results = []
def fun1():
    active = False
    start = None
    for i in range(il):
        condition = i % 9 == 0
        if not active and condition:
            active = True
            start = i
        condition2 = i % 13 == 0
        if active and condition2:
            active = False
            # do some additional calculations...
            results.append((start, i))
    if active:
        # do some additional calculations...
        results.append((start, il))
    return results

def fun2():
    a=b=0
    while b<il:
        yield (a,b)
        b=b+13
        a=a+9
        while a<=b-13:
            a=a+9
    if a<il:
        yield (a,il)

print fun1()
print
print [(a,b) for (a,b) in fun2()]
```

Please check the code for different values of il and compare it to your function before you use it.